# Auto split large files with bash in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I need to cron a bash which should split files larger than 50 GB in a certain directory (not recursively) in linux. Can someone please guide me.

Like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -size +49G -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

How can I send each filename to split command as parameter ?

```
split --bytes=30G $filenameoffoundfile $filenameoffoundfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just combine them as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +49G -exec split --bytes=30G {} {} \;
```